# Is it correct to use "since" with the verb hate or like?

Tags: present-simple, since

Can I say, for example:

> I hate math since I was in primary school!

or

> I hated math since I was in primary school!

Can I use "since" with the present simple tense?

Answer (score 19):

> I hate math since I was in primary school!

means that being in primary school caused you to hate math. It is the same as saying, "I hate math because I was in primary school."

To say that you started hating math in primary school and still hate it, you would say,

> I have hated math ever since I was in primary school.

Comment: Your second example sentence is most correct, however, the OPs second example `I hated math since I was in primary school!` has become common usage and few would blink twice at hearing it. Some would shudder, though, and all should.

Comment: @FreeMan OTOH "I hated math since I had a lousy teacher" would be understood as a cause. The past tense suggests that they no longer hate it.

Comment: "Since" should not be used as a synonym for "because," precisely because the meaning is unclear. Use "since" for placement in time only. That's longstanding AP Style Guide advice.

Comment: @FreeMan Has it?  I haven't heard such usage personally. Is it regional perhaps? Do you know of any examples I could look up? Such a change seems believable based on people being lazy and "I've hated" sounding so similar to "I hated".

Comment: @user8356 It is like that because mentioning a temporal chain is often the same as suggesting a causal link. Since this - then that.

Comment: 'ever' in the example sentence is superfluous, I understand it's a common phrasing, but so is the sentence without it. Given it's a 'language learner' forum, not just a language forum, I think it'd be better not to include it for fear of implying its necessity - not even suggesting and edit, up to you, just my two cents

Comment: Your first sentence seems deliberately designed to confuse the OP. Don't do this! Yes, you are perfectly correct; but your cleverness is the opposite of helpful.

Answer (score 13):

A native speaker isn't likely to say either of those - you'd expect to see either

> I've hated math since primary school!

or

> I've hated math ever since I was in primary school!

or even

> I've hated math since I was in primary school

Without the "have" (in "I've") or the "ever" in the second example as the other answer states, the "since" is taking on it's definition of "because" rather than "from this time" - "I hated X since Y" could imply Y is the cause of hating X.

Comment: Most people will understand "I've hated math since I was in primary school!" to mean the same as "I've hated math ever since I was in primary school!" The suggestion that omitting "ever" changes the meaning to "because" seems incorrect; people can work out which meaning is more likely from context, and it makes no sense at all for somebody to say "I've hated math because I was in primary school!"

Comment: I think both examples in this answer mean time. The first one does not mean reason. Even if you change "since primary school" to "since I was in primary school" I still think it means time.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The "ever" does clarify the meaning though.  "I've hated math since I was in primary school!" *could* mean "because", but "I've hated math ever since I was in primary school!" clearly refers to time.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist OP didn't say "I've hated" though, he said "I hated" - there he uses the "have" to provide the temporal aspect. Although a native speaker would probably understand all of those to convey the meaning, it's less ambiguous. I've clarified a bit.

Comment: Re *"A native speaker isn't likely to say either of those"*: Indeed. It often comes from word-for-word *direct translation* from the native language (e.g., "[seit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seit)" in German - the OP's screen name suggests German). A typical example is *"Since two years, I have..."* vs. *"For the past two year, I have"*